# How to rewrite (copy) columns into existing SQLite database

Tags: r, sqlite

How to rewrite (copy) columns into existing database

I have database named db.sqlite

```
r.memory.data <- data.frame(id=seq(1,10),year=paste0("200",0:9),name=letters[1:10],mark=rbinom(10,1,0.5),label=letters[1:10])

con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("SQLite"), dbname = "C:/ ...db.sqlite")
list.tab <- dbListTables(con)
list.tab
```

gives  `"data"   "sqlite_data"`

```
tdf <- dbReadTable(con,"data")
```

gives:

```
[1] id  year   name     mark   label  
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I would like to rewrite the existing db ("data") with already named columns as seen above (empty columns) with dataframe r.memory.data

Attempt to rewrite (copy the data):

```
query <- paste0("INSERT INTO data SELECT * FROM r.memory.data")
dbSendQuery(con, query)
```

gives error:

```
Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement) : 
error in statement: no such table: r.memory.data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dbWriteTable(con, name="data", value=r.memory.data, overwrite=T)
```

That is how I would try to do it